# Stepping down low voltage AC

Tags: voltage

This seems like basic Ohm's Law electricity stuff.  But before I blow something out, I want to get a second opinion.  I have a model train transformer the has a 20 volt AC accessory output.  I recently purchased 30 low voltage (3 volt) LED street lamps.  The package claims they work on both AC or DC.  These are marked used only with 3 volt system.  The manufacturer even included a package of resistors to wire "in series" with each lamp if connecting to a 12 or 15 volt power supply.

Nowhere on the package is there anything to indicate that multiple lamps could be wired in series.

It seems obvious to me that I could wire 7 lamps in series and be within the 3 volt requirement.  Other than they will burn ever so slightly dimmer as 7 lamps is equivalent to 21 volts (not 20).  Additionally, I recognize that if one burns out, the entire series will be dead.  Is there something about LED lights that makes this infeasible or damaging?

Comment: There are quite literally hundreds of questions on this site about how to drive LEDs properly. Why don't you use the search feature to learn how to do this. If you want proper answers to this question I suggest that you provide hyper-links to the part data sheets.

Comment: I'd use the manufacturer's 'one LED 12-15 V' resistors, to control the series string current to one LED, then put another 2 or 3 LEDs in series to bring the nominal voltage up to around 20 V, so all three or four get the same current. This takes up tolerances in power supply output, and LED forward voltage drop, safely.